# Find duplicate records across one-to-many relationship tables

Tags: join, duplication

Let's say I have two tables that have a one-to-many relationship: People and Attributes. I'm trying to find duplicates based on the first_name, last_name, and all attributes must match exactly.

```
CREATE TABLE People (Id int, 
                 first_name varchar(100), 
                 last_name varchar(100));

CREATE TABLE Attributes (Id int, 
                     person_id int, 
                     field varchar(100),
                     field_value varchar(100));

INSERT INTO People VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith');
INSERT INTO People VALUES (2, 'John', 'Smith');
INSERT INTO People VALUES (3, 'John', 'Smith');

INSERT INTO Attributes VALUES (1, 1, 'HairColor', 'Brown');
INSERT INTO Attributes VALUES (2, 1, 'EyeColor', 'Blue');
INSERT INTO Attributes VALUES (3, 2, 'HairColor', 'Brown');
INSERT INTO Attributes VALUES (4, 2, 'EyeColor', 'Blue');
INSERT INTO Attributes VALUES (5, 3, 'HairColor', 'Blonde');
```

Which gives us:

```
 id | first_name | last_name
----+------------+-----------
  1 | John       | Smith
  2 | John       | Smith
  3 | John       | Smith

 id | person_id |   field   | field_value
----+-----------+-----------+-------------
  1 |         1 | HairColor | Brown
  2 |         1 | EyeColor  | Blue
  3 |         2 | HairColor | Brown
  4 |         2 | EyeColor  | Blue
  5 |         3 | HairColor | Blonde
```

I'd like a query that will return IDs 1 and 2 from the People table. I can find duplicates within a single table:

```
select first_name,last_name,count(*) from People 
    group by first_name,last_name having ( count(*) > 1 );
```

But I'm having trouble joining the one-to-many table and detecting duplicates across both tables. How can I detect duplicates across tables that have a one-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this (check the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/872d2/2)):

```
select 
    p1.id as id1, 
    p2.id as id2
from people p1
  join people p2
    on  p1.first_name = p2.first_name
    and p1.last_name = p2.last_name
    and p1.id < p2.id
where not exists
    ( select 1
      from 
      ( select * 
        from attributes a1
        where a1.person_id = p1.id
      union all
        select * 
        from attributes a2
        where a2.person_id = p2.id
      ) g
      group by field, field_value
      having count(*) <> 2
   ) ;
```

and another:

```
select 
    p1.id as id1, 
    p2.id as id2
from people p1
  join people p2
    on  p1.first_name = p2.first_name
    and p1.last_name = p2.last_name
    and p1.id < p2.id
where not exists
    ( ( select field, field_value
        from attributes a1
        where a1.person_id = p1.id
      union 
        select field, field_value
        from attributes a2
       where a2.person_id = p2.id
      ) 
    except
      ( select field, field_value
        from attributes a1
        where a1.person_id = p1.id
      intersect
        select field, field_value
        from attributes a2
        where a2.person_id = p2.id
      )
    ) ;
```

Intersect has higher precedence than except/minus, at least in Postgres and SQL Server. Just to be safe, you can use parentheses, to ensure the precedence.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a take using T-SQL syntax, which you could change to use `LIMIT 1` rather than `TOP 1` if you really need standard syntax. Hope this helps, but it looks like [ypercube has you covered](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91975) either way.

```
SELECT TOP 1
            MIN(p.Id) AS id1,
            MAX(a.person_id) AS id2
    FROM    dbo.People AS p
            CROSS JOIN dbo.Attributes AS a
    WHERE   p.Id = a.person_id
    GROUP BY p.first_name ,
            p.last_name ,
            a.field ,
            a.field_value
    HAVING  COUNT(*) = ( SELECT COUNT(a2.person_id)
                         FROM   dbo.Attributes AS a2
                         WHERE  a2.field = a.field
                                AND a2.field_value = a.field_value
                       );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your attributes are more-or-less fixed, and you don't mind doing a code release when the attribute list changes, then unrolling them with JOINs and a COUNT would do it, too.

```
select
    p.Id,
    a1.field_value,
    a2.field_value
from People as p
left outer join Attributes as a1
    on a1.person_id = p.Id
    and a1.field = 'HairColor'
left outer join Attributes as a2
    on a2.person_id = p.Id
    and a2.field = 'EyeColor'
group by
    p.Id,
    a1.field_value,
    a2.field_value
having
    count(*) > 1;
```

Effective, but not elegant, and potentially slow if you have many people and many attributes.